# Непонятная фамилия

Tags: словообразование

Меня очень интересует корень в моей девичьей фамилии Предеина? Обозначает он *ДЕЛО* или *ДЕЙСТВО*? Но тогда была бы приставка **ПРИ**. ***ПРИ ДЕЙСТВЕ*** - находящиеся при действе например. Или здесь два корня? **ПРЕД** и **ЕИ**? ПРЕДОК ИХ или *ПРЕД НИМИ* - например. Хотелось бы разобраться самой, но маловато знаний. Одни вымыслы! А как ВЫ ДУМАЕТЕ?

Comment: Попробуйте ещё спросить вот здесь. там именно этим занимаются. http://www.genway.ru/lib/allfam/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%BD/?keyfam=%D0%9F&page=72

Comment: **Людмила**, вот где угодно, только не там. Это полнейшая лажа. Там анализом занимаются боты.
Забейте фамилию ЧерезЗаборНогуЗадерищинский - получите вполне аналогичные результаты.
Проходили уже. Здесь: [Фамилия Брюллов](http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/6683)

Answer (score 2):

Нашел а Интернете, глубоко не вникал, но навскидку - версия вполне правдоподобная.
Единственное утонение: порождающим именем должно быть *Предея*, от *Предей* было бы *Предеев*

Основой фамилии Предеин послужило мирское имя Предей. Скорее всего, фамилия Предеин связана со старинным именем Предей, которое было во всех славянских языках и являлось сокращенной формой таких сложных имен, как Предимир, Предислав. Кроме того, Предей употреблялось как самостоятельное имя со значением «быть впереди, быть первым». Таким образом, Предеем могли называть торопливого человека.

Менее вероятно, что фамилия имеет румынские корни и происходит от глагола preda — «сдавать, отдавать, передавать, преподавать». Предей, со временем получил фамилию Предеин.

[Происхождение фамилии Предеин](http://www.ufolog.ru/names/order/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%BD)

Comment: Благодарю Вас! Мне теперь очень многое становится ясным. Мои ближайшие родственники по отцовой линии, появились в курганской области от румынских цыган. Но странное дело - я абсолютно не приемлю золото. Какая же я тогда цыганка? Шучу. Но зато, я обнаружила (уже после 40 лет) в себе способности преподавать и стала из архитектора, учителем рисования.